# Outer div should adjust to image size

Tags: html, css

I have code like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img_url" alt="" />
</div>​
```

Container's width has set on 600px but if image is bigger, container's width should adjust to image size.
How I should fix my css?

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #2a2929;
    border: 1px solid #212020;    
}

.container img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gzjp7/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to the container img

```
width:100%;
height:auto;
```

that should keep the image within the container

Answer (score 2):

Sen `min-width` on the container, instead of `width`.

This will ensure that the `div` will have at least `400px` width, and will expand if necessary.

```
.container {
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 400px;
    background-color: #2a2929;
    border: 1px solid #212020;    
}
```

If you don't want a minimal width for your container then just omit the `width` property, or set it to `auto` (which is the default).